# Django / Model Forms

Tags: python, django

Completely new to all computer programming and trying to build an app that tracks my smoking habits. The first step was creating a Django model called packs:

```
class packs (models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=False)
    num_packs = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length=10)
    cost_packs = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

Next I created a forms.py page and this is where I started getting lost:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import packs

class packsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = packs
        fields = ['num_packs', 'cost_packs']
```

Of course that led to my failure in HTML trying to render a page that has all the form data:

```
{%block content%}

<div class = "form_pack">
    <h3>FORM PACK</h3>
    <p>
        <form method="POST" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
            <input text="cost_pack" name=cost_pack>
            {{ form }}
     <input type="submit" value="save"/>
</form>
    </p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

To help my view.py looks like this:

```
def packs_create(request):
     form=packsForm(request.POST or None)
     if form.is_valid():
          return render(request, 'pack/index.htmnl', {'form': form})
```

Now when I refresh the page I don't get the form. Just the one input i put in.

Can someone help me sort out which path I got lost in and where I need to connect the dots? I believe my forms.py is not complete, but not sure where to progress...

Thanks,

DrKornballer

Comment: The usual way to render a form is `{{ form.as_p }}` or `{{ form.as_table }}`.

Comment: thanks. I made that change. I think something is missing in the forms.py section. Its still not rendering a form.

Comment: What does packs_create() render if form.is_valid() is false? Do you have a separate view?  I also see a typo in 'pack/index.htmnl' which makes me think that your view is not being called. Did you add a url for your view? https://atufashireen.medium.com/making-your-first-django-app-281cb41d9f53

Answer (score 0):

Just update your [views.py](/questions/tagged/views.py) and  [forms.py](/questions/tagged/forms.py) you will get your form and can save the data entered.

[views.py](/questions/tagged/views.py)

```
def packs_create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = packsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit = True)
    else:
        form = PacksForm()
        return render(request, 'pack/index.html', {'form': form})
```

[forms.py](/questions/tagged/forms.py)

```
class packsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = packs
        fields = ('num_packs', 'cost_packs')
```

Comment: Thanks! That def helped. I added the form = packForm() to my main pack view and it ended up rendering. Problem now is its not recording new data. I guess thats the next goal.

Comment: did u add 
`if form.is_valid():
 form.save(commit = True)`

Comment: yeah I did and its still not working. here's my latest code: